# Is elementary-tweaks still working on Hera?

Tags: release-hera, tweak-tool

Does it still working on elementary OS Hera? is it safe to install?

Thanks and sorry for the odd question!

Comment: Just installed them the other day on 5.1 Hera - yes, they work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes `elementary-tweak` work very well with Hera's release.

I have it and I have no problem with. Like say [@Bo_rislav](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/12483/bo-rislav) :

> *Of course if you set a broken theme or something the layout will be*
>   *broken but the os will not be destroyed if this is what you ask.*

Here the link to the Github's project :
https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

---

## INSTALLATION

```
# Make sure you have software-properties-common
sudo apt search software-properties-common

# Output exemple
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
software-properties-common/bionic,bionic,now 0.96.24.32.11+elementary7~ubuntu5.0.1 all [installed]
  manage the repositories that you install software from (common)

# If it is not installed do it
sudo apt install software-properties-common

# Install elementary-tweaks
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

And if you want to remove the PPA as you suggest [@duality](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/19745/duality) you can do

```
# Remove ppa connection
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is usable, personally I would install then remove the ppa:

```
# Make sure you have software-properties-common
sudo apt install software-properties-common

# Install elementary-tweaks
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks

#Remove ppa connection
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they works. The developper pretend that the way they are built is safe for the sysytem, as long as I know there is no any harm for the system by using elementary tweaks. Of course if you set a broken theme or something the layout will be broken but the os will not be destroyed if this is what you ask.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. Thanks for the info!

Comment: You can vote for the answers you find useful with the arrows also. If you don't have enough rating, your vote will be saved and not shown at the moment, but it helps for the community to understand which answers are helpful and which not.

Comment: Yeah, I new here, also new in Linux... learning so much stuff in here! thanks again.